# Character encoding in R

Tags: r, character-encoding

I am trying to read a `csv` file generated by Sql Server Management Studio and encoded as `UTF-8`  (I chose that option when saving it) into `R` version 3.0.1 (x64) through `read.csv2()`. I can't get R to display special characters correctly.

If I set `fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM"` the import stops at the line where I have a ÿ. However, when opening the file in `Notepad++` the ÿ is displayed correctly with `UTF-8` encoding. I have tried without setting `fileEncoding`, but then the special characters aren't displayed correctly (of course).

The csv flie is available here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7y47i826ikq8ahi/Data.csv

How do I read the csv file and display the text in the right encoding?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer my self. The problem was with the transformantion from UTF-8 to the system locale (the default encoding in R) through `fileEncoding`. As I use `RStudio`, I just changed the default encoding to UTF-8 and removed the `fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM"` from `read.csv`. Then, the entire csv file was read and RStudio displays all characters correctly.

Answer (score 2):

To those that are still stuck with this issue. My scripts were able to recognise "umlaute" (ä, ö, ü, or ß) by including a line at the top of the script that changes the default option for character encoding `options(encoding = "UTF-8")` (In my case setting the options in RStudio direclty didn't effect the encodings!).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have this issue in R inside a docker container (debian and R), when I ran `locale` in the container all variables appeared empty. I solve the problem adding this in the Dockerfile.

```
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_NUMERIC=es_AR.UTF-8
ENV LC_TIME=es_AR.UTF-8
ENV LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_MONETARY=es_AR.UTF-8
ENV LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_PAPER=es_AR.UTF-8
ENV LC_NAME=es_AR.UTF-8
ENV LC_ADDRESS=es_AR.UTF-8
ENV LC_TELEPHONE=es_AR.UTF-8
ENV LC_MEASUREMENT=es_AR.UTF-8
ENV LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_AR.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```

I have `es_AR` in some values, but I think `en_US` or other should work.