# Best practice: Should I try to change to UTF-8 as locale or is it safe to leave it as is?

Tags: r, windows, encoding, utf-8

I try to set my default encoding to UTF-8; up to now without success:

```
a <- "Hallo"
b <- "äöfd"
print(Encoding(a))
# [1] "unknown"
print(Encoding(b))
# [1] "latin1"

options(encoding = "UTF-8")
a <- "Hallo"
b <- "äöfd"
print(Encoding(a))
# [1] "unknown"
print(Encoding(b))
# [1] "latin1"

old_locale <- Sys.getlocale()
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "English_United States.1252")
a <- "Hallo"
b <- "äöfd"
print(Encoding(a))
# [1] "unknown"
print(Encoding(b))
# [1] "latin1"

Sys.getlocale()
# [1] "LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252;
# LC_CTYPE=German_Switzerland.1252;
# LC_MONETARY=German_Switzerland.1252;
# LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=German_Switzerland.1252"
```

I found the following links [R Encoding for files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099375/character-encoding-in-r?rq=1) and [How to use Sys.setlocale()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577764/set-locale-to-system-default-utf-8) but as you can see it seems they don't work in my case and I don't understand why.

I also tried `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "en_US.UTF-8")` but got

> Warning message: In Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale =
>   "en_US.UTF-8") :   OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.UTF-8"
>   cannot be honored

In `cmd` the command `systeminfo & pause` gives

> Systemgebietsschema:                           de-ch;Deutsch (Schweiz)
>   Eingabegebietsschema:                          de-ch;Deutsch (Schweiz)

**Edit**:

- I fear that `"unknown"` encoding could lead to mistakes which I am not aware and
- I thought that it was good to use the new standard UTF-8 to avoid problems like the one I had.
- Last but not least I would like to be able to get reproducible results - a colleague is working on a Mac (with less issues concerning encoding)...

**Edit2:** What is the experience with this issue? Is there any best practice?

Comment: I doubt that this is possible on a Windows system, but even if it is, you'd probably get into trouble quickly. Why do you want this?

Comment: @Roland See my edit. I write the code in english (scripts and packages). As soon as I start to use the console involving data from customers I need the Umlaute and I run into trouble.

Comment: 1) The problem you linked to was fixed in an R update. 2) I don't think Windows supports UTF-8 sufficiently to make it the default. (But I could be wrong.) 3) I'm German and problems with Umlaute (which are part of the default latin1 character set) are so rare that I can hardly remember the last time (I think it was related to data.table and its join optimizations, which I could switch off easily).

Comment: Ok. I feared, I could run into more trouble. But then perhaps everything is fine. Could you write your comment as answer? What would you advice: Change imported data to local `latin1`? In case I could modify the title of the question (E.g. "Is it a problem if I don't have UTF-8 as locale?")

Comment: I don't feel sufficiently knowledgeable about this to post an answer. Encoding problems are one of my nightmares. I can just say that they have been very rare for me when using R.

Comment: The bottom line is that UTF-8 and Windows don't play well, as noted by Roland. I have given up and have a dual boot into a lightweight linux distribution which handles this seamlessly.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik is it possible to pinpoint let's say the three most frequently met problems (which I may face in my constellation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a perfect answer but a good workaround: As Roland pointed out, it might be dangerous to change the locale. So leave it as is. If you have a file and you run into trouble, just search for non-UTF8 encoding as discribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40989344/how-can-i-detect-non-utf-8-encoding-in-rstudio) for `RStudio`. What I saw, most Editors have such a feature.

Furthermore, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41747709/5784831) answer gives more insight in what you can do in case you `source()` a file.

For a way to deal with locales when collations play a crucial part see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63934762/5784831)

---

**Edit some years later**: I realized, that Windows allows you to change some settings which also affects R/RStudio:

[image]
In this German setting e.g. (after restart RStudio):

```
format(Sys.time(), "%a")
# [1] "Mo" # without "."
```

Then...

[image]

In this Swiss setting e.g. (after restart RStudio):

```
format(Sys.time(), "%a")
# [1] "Mo." # WITH "."
```

**Although this setting does NOT affect `LC_TIME=German_Switzerland.1252`**

Comment: Since you edited your answer just now it might be worth mentioning that R now finally supports universal multibyte encodings on Windows via the UCRT runtime. I.e. R *finally* has proper support for UTF-8 on Windows. All the faffing about with code pages is no longer required (nor recommended).

Comment: @KonradRudolph ? Perhaps it's time for a short answer? As you can see from my answer, I am not an expert here and just tried to get through. Your support would still be highly appreciated :-)