# Rstudio bug with encoding

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a strange error. When I try to build the package in Rstudio in the Build window I get this Error. I mean this ��� symbols.

[image]

- I tried to set Encoding: cp1251 and Encoding: UTF-8 in the
  'DESCRIPTION' it did not help.
- I tried to run Rstudio in compatibility mode with Windows 7 and run
  as administrator it did not help.
- I tried to set the Project Options -> Text encoding -> UTF-8 and
  Global options -> Code -> save -> Default text encoding -> UTF-8 and
  it didn't help.

P.S. My system is Windows 10 x64 English. And English and Russian Languages

Comment: This is not Rstudio related but with encoding in Windows. Windows are not keen on utf-8.

Comment: I have the same issue. Here is [what I figured out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632751/best-practice-should-i-try-to-change-to-utf-8-as-locale-or-is-it-save-to-leave). At first I also thought it was a problem of RStudio...

Comment: Two things worth trying: 1) Re-save all files in the package with the default system encoding and try again; 2) Re-save all files in the package with UTF-8 encoding and specify `Encoding: UTF-8` in the `DESCRIPTION` file. (Note that option 2 might require a new-ish version of R)